# how can I seal a leaky coupling nut on my toilet??? using T-joint for bidet attachment

Tags: bathroom, toilet, leak, valve

I am trying to install a bidet attachment to my toilet.

In a nutshell, you have to detach the supply line from the fill valve and add a T-joint. This T-joint will then run water to the bidet attachment, and also allow the supply line to be reconnected.

See below image.

[image: bidet attachment]

The problem is, when I reattach everything, the supply line connection to the T-joint is now leaking. It does not leak when attached to the fill valve so I think there is some imperfections with the T-join threads (??)

My supply line looks like this, and looks like it has some rubber inside for making the seal

[image: similar line]

My first thought was just to use plumbers tape but I read they should not be used on connections like this.

Any suggestions? I don't believe the supply line is the issue because it works fine without the T-joint so dont think replacing it would do anything...

Much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you did not over tighten , you are correct on the 2 hose fittings not to use plumbers tape is there an oring in the T ?

Comment: perhaps I did overtighten...I can try again, but I didn't go too tight and it was dripping and started tightening it a little bit to see if it would fix it but didnt seem to do anything...there is not an o-ring in the T but there is a rubber gasket(? not sure what to call it) thats part of the supply line connection inside the plastic, if you look at the second picture

Comment: You may be correct on the T joint but in this case the threads do not do the sealing. The oring or flat rubber gasket makes the seal if there is an imperfection in the surface or the seal was cut on the T from over tightening that well may be the problem.

Comment: definitely seems to be the T-joint that is the issue, the supply line connects to the fill valve without leaking no problem..any suggestions how I could improve the seal without having to go through the trouble of replace the t-joint with one that's not a POS?

Comment: Just replace the gasket in the supply line hose.

Comment: @Programmer66 is that necessary if it doesnt leak when connected to the fill valve? or do you think it will just help make the seal better on the t-joint

Comment: Yes, a better seal, plus I would try using a layer of plumber tape on the thread on the Tee.